# How does Google Cloud SQL Performance Tiers compare with Amazon AWS RDS for MySQL?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, google-cloud-sql, amazon-rds

There are only 7 performance tiers in GCS (D0, D1, D2, D4, D8, D16, D32), RAM maxes out at 16GB (D32) as they are based on Google Compute Engine(GCE) machine types. See screenshot below ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpO1a.png))

By comparison, Amazon has 13 performance tiers with `db.r3.8xlarge`'s RAM maxes out at 244GB. ([2](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/mysql/details/))

So my question is, what is the rough equivalent performance tier in AWS RDS for MySQL for a Google Cloud SQL's D32 tier?

Disclaimer: I am new to Google Cloud SQL. I only start to use Cloud SQL because I started a new job that's 100% Google Cloud. Previously I have been a AWS user since the early days.

[image: Google Cloud SQL instance tiers in Google Cloud Console screenshot]

Comment: One of the ones closest to 16 GB RAM on http://aws.amazon.com/rds/pricing/, I'd imagine. Google doesn't really give you much info on the CPU for better comparison, so I'd guess it's similar to the AWS db.m3.xlarge.

Answer (score 1):

The D0-D32 Cloud SQL tiers are not based on GCE VMs so a direct comparison is not straightforward. Note that the storage for D0-D32 is replicated geographically and that makes writes a lot slower. The ASYNC mode improves the performance for small commits. The upside is that the instances can be relocated quickly between location that are farther apart.

The connectivity for Cloud SQL is also different from RDS. RDS can be access using IPs and the latency is comparable with VMs talking over local IPs. Cloud SQL uses only external IPs. That makes the latency from GCE higher (~1.25ms) but it provides a slightly better for experience for connections coming from outside the Google Cloud because the TCP connections are terminated closer to the clients.

That being said, from a memory point of view, the `db.m3.xlarge` from RDS  is the closest match for the D32 from Cloud SQL. If the working set fits in the memory the performance for some queries will be similar.

Comment: The latency difference between mysql on GCE using internal IP and Google SQL using external IP, what kind of latency differences, actual numbers, could I expect for communicating with a website on GCE?

Answer (score 0):

Currently in Alpha, there is a new feature of Cloud SQL that uses comparable performance to GCE machine types.

> A Google Cloud SQL Performance Class instance is a new Google Cloud
>   SQL instance type that provides better performance and more storage
>   capacity, and is optimized for heavy workloads running on Google
>   Compute Engine. The new instance type is an always-on, long-lived
>   database as compared to a Standard Class instance type. Performance
>   Class instances are based on tiers that correspond to Google Compute
>   Engine (GCE) standard or highmem machine types.

Link: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/getting-started-performance-class

Anyway, very good question, comparing prices with AWS, I found out that there is a huge difference in resources for the smallest instances and the same price:

- GCE, D0 = $0.025 per hour (0,128 GB RAM + "an appropriate amount of CPU")
- AWS, db.t2.micro = $0.02 per hour (**1 GB RAM** + 1 vCPU)

For 1 GB RAM in GCE, one would have to pay $0.19 per hour. Unfortunately Google does not specify anything about SSD storage, something very important for performance comparison.

Comment: We've been using CloudSQL in production environment. Performance was the least impressive aspect of it to say at best.